# Can this code work or not

Tags: php, mysql

Can the code below work or not to retrieve data from database and display.. I know that the sql4 can't work  in a mysql database can the php code below make it work or not.

```
<?php

include 'connect.php'; 
$sql2 = "SELECT * from pm Order by mid";

while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)) {
   $sql4 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reply ORDER BY mid =".$row3["$mid"]."  ");
   $row4 = mysql_fetch_array($sql4);
   echo"<trid='".$mid."'><td><img src='a/$name' width='150' height='100' /></td>     <td>".$row['mid']."</td></tr><tr><td>".$row['reply']."</td></tr>"; 
}

?>
```

esp. this mysql or mysql and php combined. Basically is the code below improper. I think it is.

```
<?php

$sql4 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reply ORDER BY mid =".$row3["$mid"]."  ");

?>
```

Comment: Why don't you run it and see, whether it can work?

Comment: i did run it but it nothing displays but sometimes their are usually little errors that can prevent data from being displayed. Do you know if     $sql4 = mysql_query ("SELECT * from reply Order by mid =".$row3["$mid"]."  ");   is improper

Comment: Using `mysql_` itself is "improper".

Comment: And this will surely fire up another error `<trid=`

Answer (score 2):

Put the following at the top of your PHP file and try it out yourself:

```
<?php

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set("display_errors", true);

// Your code goes here

?>
```

(I think the code is self-explaining)

Comment: thanks for such a nice hint

Comment: I think you learn much more if you debug your code yourself. Of course I could debug it for you here, but the learning effect wouldn't be as intense. Also use the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to validate your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Try...

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * from pm Order by mid";

$result = mysql_query($sql2); <- MISSING THIS LINE

while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    // OTHER CODE HERE
    }
```

Comment: oh no. i Already know how to do this. I was trying to do something else. Thanks anyway,.

Comment: Then why didn't your code show this?

Comment: ah, i was trying to do something else and not a regular code.

Comment: oh i get what you where trying to do. Does that code actually work.

Comment: Try it... You never executed the sql statement so the while loop would never run.